# how to use Ajax with ASP.NET MVC4 Enterprise application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

i am going to develop a new application and i have decided to use asp.net mvc4 framework.

my project is very large and i would to make a professional work,now my problem is how to use ajax for such an application.

when i tried to think to use j query ajax i found that i'll make ajax request for each entry form and it would take more time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: sURL ,
            data: {
//Form data to submit to controller .....},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {     
            alert(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make some service function that does ajax requests and receives url and data to send.

```
 dataService=function(url,data)
   {
   return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url ,
        data: data
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",    
    });
  };
```

Your dataservice method (ajax requests) returns promise object which means you can do something like:

```
     dataService("firstUrl","firstAjaxCallData")
     .then(function(){ console.log("this happens after sucessfull ajax call")});
```